# How to reconstruct a Git branch?

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch and a `es` branch. `es` has been reconstructed locally:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b es2
git cherry-pick A C E D 
git branch -D es
git checkout master
git branch -m es2 es
```

where A, C, D and E are some selected commits in the `es` branch.

After this I have had to force a push:

```
git push --all -f
```

From the beginning until this point nobody has pushed or pulled from the repo.

But everything has gone well. The problem appeared when I tried to rebase a branch in another computer. This user has this branch structure:

```
master - es - dev
```

`dev` has only one commit (say X). This is the problematic sequence of git commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git branch -f es origin/es
git checkout dev
git rebase es
```

The last rebase produce a lot of conflicts with commits that aren't included in the new `es` branch, but they are included in `master` branch. After doing some digging we have found that we can reconstruct the structure by doing this instead of the rebase:

```
git checkout es
git checkout -b dev2
git cherry-pick X
git branch -D dev
git checkout es
git branch -m dev2 dev
```

This makes me think that the problem is that the "old" `dev` branch has some reference or link to the old `es` branch and that's why the rebase tries to add to the `dev` branch more than the X commit. I'm wondering if there is another cleaner way to make the users dev folder resynchronize with the repository branches.

NOTE: users **never** change `es` or `master`, just `dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you tried to do the `rebase`, you needed to use the `--onto` flag to tell git to `rebase` the `dev` branch onto the new `es` branch. Using the regular `rebase` would have only worked if the `es` branch still had the original commits on it, because that's what `rebase` uses as a reference point to figure out how to redo the `dev` branch on top of `es`.

So the simpler way to do what you wanted would have been

```
git rebase --onto <new-base> <old-base> <branch>
git rebase --onto origin/es es dev
```

This tells git to take the `dev` branch and rebase it onto the version of `es` from the `origin`, and it says to use the local, original version of `es` as a reference point to figure out what to exclude in the rebase (i.e., it will take all commits between `es` and `dev`, but not including `es` itself).

Note that if you already have the `dev` branch checked out, then you can leave it out of the `rebase` command:

```
git rebase --onto origin/es es
```